# java unreachable code error (Render class game development)

Tags: java, game-engine

i have been working on a java game engine but my render keeps getting the unreachable code error.The error appears at the setPixels method.

```
public class Renderer {

    private int width, height;
    private byte[] pixels;


    public Renderer(GameContainer gc){
        width = gc.getWidth();
        height = gc.getHeight();
        pixels = ((DataBufferByte)gc.getWindow().getImage().getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }

    public void setPixel(int x, int y, float a, float r, float g, float b){

        if((x < 0 || x>= width || y < 0 || y>= height) || a == 0){
            return;

            int index = (x + y * width) * 4;
            pixels[index] = (byte)((a * 255f) + 0.5f);
            pixels[index + 1] = (byte)((b * 255f) + 0.5f);
            pixels[index + 2] = (byte)((g * 255f) + 0.5f);
            pixels[index + 3] = (byte)((r * 255f) + 0.5f);

        }
    }

    public void clear(){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                setPixel(x,y,1,0,1,1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen after the `return;` statement? When should all those `pixels[..]` assignment happen?

Comment: In your if-statement, you return before you do the pixel[index] stuff. You will never reach that.

Comment: kk thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do?
Your `if` statement should not be enclosing all the statements in your function.

```
public void setPixel(int x, int y, float a, float r, float g, float b){

    // Check for invalid values
    if((x < 0 || x>= width || y < 0 || y>= height) || a == 0){
        // Break out of function if invalid values detected
        return;
    }

    // Update pixel
    int index = (x + y * width) * 4;
    pixels[index] = (byte)((a * 255f) + 0.5f);
    pixels[index + 1] = (byte)((b * 255f) + 0.5f);
    pixels[index + 2] = (byte)((g * 255f) + 0.5f);
    pixels[index + 3] = (byte)((r * 255f) + 0.5f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement ends the execution of a method. In the event that the `if` statement is run in the code below, the method will hit the `return` and end before doing all the other stuff. You don't seem to need a `return` statement in `setPixel` since there isn't a need to end the method prematurely.

```
public void setPixel(int x, int y, float a, float r, float g, float b) {
    if((x < 0 || x>= width || y < 0 || y>= height) || a == 0){
        //return;

        int index = (x + y * width) * 4;
        pixels[index] = (byte)((a * 255f) + 0.5f);
        pixels[index + 1] = (byte)((b * 255f) + 0.5f);
        pixels[index + 2] = (byte)((g * 255f) + 0.5f);
        pixels[index + 3] = (byte)((r * 255f) + 0.5f);

    }
}
```